Minifig ID Assistance
Ahoy hoy,
I’ve recently moved to a town that’s main import is old people, and decided to check out some local antique stores.
Can anyone identify any of the minifigs? Or are they all just random flotsam/jetsam?


I remember many of those minifigs from my childhood. So it cannot be “old people”.

I can see one of the soccer teams from https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3409-1

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If I count correctly, there are 65 minifigures - Presumably most of them are generic ones, but properly identifying each one would be a task way too daunting to ask of internet volunteers.

And none of them are worth the $10 a piece they are trying to sell them for

I'll try doing a few:

Nexo Knights - Aaron Fox

Chima - Lion torso & legs with a Crug (crocodile) mask

Extreme Team - Red

Race - Red Scorpion

Minifigures Series 11 - Lady Robot (complete with base)

Harry Potter - Executioner (holding an axe)

Harry Potter - Ron Weasley, dark tan sweater

Police - City Bandit (without backpack; with ball & chain)

Aquazone - Aquashark 1

Harry Potter - Harry Potter, black suit
I'll let someone else do the Ninjago ones

Here are a few I know:

Vermillion warrior (Tanin I think): https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=njo295#T=I

Cole, from ghost series (But missing his armour): https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=njo140#T=I

Jay, from Prime empire, again missing armour: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=njo633#T=I
Not sure about this one:

Mr E but with the same helmet as  the vermilion, and missing armour: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=njo385#T=I
